# Bootstrap CSS files do not load in PDF usinf Flying Saucer core

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, flying-saucer

I have searched two days, but can not find a solution. I have to make a `pdf` form that has to open in a browser. I decided to use `flying saucer library`.In html my internal CSS class loads successfully, but Bootstrap does not load.

Here is my Java code:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream html2PdfGenerator() {
        context.setVariable("baseUrl", getCurrentBaseUrl());

        String processedHtml = templateEngine.process("mainPolicy", context);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        try {

            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

            URL fontResourceURL = getClass().getResource("/static/fonts/Calibri.ttf");

            renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(fontResourceURL.getPath(),
                    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

            renderer.setDocumentFromString(processedHtml, urlBase);

            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(bos);
            renderer.finishPDF();

            bos.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            if (bos != null) {
                try {
                    bos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return bos;
    }
```

**Here is my html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>


    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>

    <link href="/css/insurance.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

My folder structure is **/resource/static/css**. `Insurance css` loads, but `bootstrap` does not. I tried to include **css with tymeleaf** but no success.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Can Bootstrap be used with FlyingSaucerPDF?

Comment: @Partho63 No. But I found this open source project: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/. It is very easy to use.

Comment: FlyingSaucerPdf not supported javascript, alternatively you can use css only framework like https://bulma.io/ and https://purecss.io/